# Network sniffing with python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, sniffing

I'm going to build an sniffing software for the university. I have some ideas but want to  hear some more. The idea is to use a passive tap on front on the firewall and so get all data...

I know C is faster but i want to do it with python any good ideas like libraries etc?

Refs:

- http://www.flyninja.net/?p=13
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-manipulating-packet-data-tool.html
- http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet

Answer (score 12):

Use [`pylibcap`](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/). It provides an interface to libpcap which is the de-facto standard for packet sniffing on linux. To parse packets, you might want to use the [`construct`](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library as it already contains a parser for TCP packets.

Here's a small example program:

```
import pcap
from construct.protocols.ipstack import ip_stack

def print_packet(pktlen, data, timestamp):
    if not data:
        return

    stack = ip_stack.parse(data)
    payload = stack.next.next.next
    print payload


p = pcap.pcapObject()
p.open_live('eth0', 1600, 0, 100)
p.setfilter('dst port 80', 0, 0)

print 'Press CTRL+C to end capture'
try:
    while True:
        p.dispatch(1, print_packet)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print # Empty line where ^C from CTRL+C is displayed
    print '%d packets received, %d packets dropped, %d packets dropped by interface' % p.stats()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use Scapy ?? It is the simplest methods as I know, see the link below:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7ZdmnxPZw8